# A better ReportViewer control?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, controls, report, reportviewer

We've been struggling with the Microsoft ASP.NET WebForms ReportViewer control for years now and are about to give up.  We could just direct our users to the native SSRS site/page for each report but then we lose all branding/control.  I see that DevExpress makes a (.NET Core?) control with claims that our exiting RDLCs can be converted, but I don't know it that one is the real deal either.

Anyone else experience our frustrations?  Is there a de facto standard that will work (and work better) for us?  We want to do what most do.. just tired that our entire report library is based on such a shoddy control from MS.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you deal with the report viewer control as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

we can 100% relate to your frustrations. You can try our alternate solution to SSRS and RDLCs, [www.dotnetreport.com](http://www.dotnetreport.com)